# How to sort 3 variables without using loops in Assembler?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I want to write a program in assembler that asks user about 3 variables, then the user write the numbers to the registers ( I know how to write that), but now I have a problem: I have to sort these 3 variables using conditional /unconditional jumps (I can't use loops). So, in my mind this program will be very long because I have to write probably 9 comparisons for each set. Do You have any ideas how to write this program much shorter?

Comment: If you have SSE4.1 or AVX, you can use `vpmaxsd xmm2, xmm1, xmm0` / `vpminsd xmm1, xmm1, xmm0` to get the min/max of a pair of numbers (in the low element of XMM registers), as a building block for a sorting network.

Comment: Naming the 3 variables a, b, c, there are 6 possible orderings, abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba, and 3 possible compares, ab,ac,bc. Without any swapping, 5 if's and 5 else's should be enough to sort a,b,c. No single path takes more than 3 if's. With swapping, it's just 3 if/swaps, similar to a sorting network as commented by Peter Cordes.

Comment: Instead of a link to your code in your comment to the answer below, you can include the code as part of your question. Put 4 spaces before every line in order to show the lines as code.

Answer (score 1):

Basic "3 value sort":

```
if(a > b) swap(a, b)
if(a > c) swap(a, c)   // a must be the smallest value now
if(b > c) swap(b, c)   // b must be the second smallest value, c must be the biggest value
```

In 32-bit 80x86 assembly (NASM syntax):

```
    cmp eax,ebx
    jna .l1
    xchg eax,ebx
.l1:
    cmp eax,ecx
    jna .l2
    xchg eax,ecx
.l2:
    cmp ebx,ecx
    jna .l3
    xchg ebx,ecx
.l3:
; eax must contain smallest value, ebx the second smallest, ecx the biggest
```

Comment: So I did as you told, but the result is bad, like random printed variables. There is my code: https://pastebin.com/jp8t8BEb

Comment: @KamilaNowak: `resb 2` reserves 2 bytes, but you're loading / storing 4 bytes, and doing weird stuff with add/sub `'0'` that has nothing to do with sorting.  **Use a debugger** to see what inputs you're providing to the sorting. Test a [mcve] of just sorting 3 registers after `mov eax, 55` / `mov ecx, 33` / `mov edx, 66` or something.